# Найдите флаг Python

Tags: python

Найдите флаг
Найти все вхождения строки формата "flag{[0-9a-f]{32}}" в файле "input.txt"

Примеры
Входные данные

flag{5c4d49102af8d43d9802cabd6b8a3619}

flag

Результат работы

flag{5c4d49102af8d43d9802cabd6b8a3619}

написал код, но не могу понять в чем проблема.

```py
import re

with open('input.txt') as fh:
    matches = re.findall(r'flag\{[0-9a-f]{32}\}', fh.read())

for m in matches:
    print(m.group(0))
```

Предлагали прописать путь до тхт, но файл отправляется на сайт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы объявили `matches` внутри `with`, чтобы ваш код сработал.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Так как `re.findall` возвращает список строк, то `m` внутри цикла `for` является строкой ,а в `Python 3.x` строка не имеет метода `group`, по этому ваш код не сработает.

Сработает так:

```
import re

with open('input.txt') as fh:
    matches = re.findall(r'flag\{[0-9a-f]{32}\}', fh.read())

    for m in matches:
        print(m)
```

Comment: Попробовал, но все равно не сработало.

Comment: А какой результат вы хотите получить?

Comment: Найти все вхождения строки в том формате, что выше)) Но сайт отказывается принимать тот код, который я выслал